# Custom keyboard shortcuts for any website

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, firefox-extensions

I'd like to be able to define my own keyboard shortcuts for websites that doesn't provide them.
I was wondering if there's any firefox add-on/userscript to enable generic keyboard shortcuts.

Here is a simple use case:
I use google translate daily translating between Hebrew & English, and often need to switch between English->Hebrew and vice versa using my mouse.
Ideally, I could inspect the DOM, pick the button I need and define a keyboard shortcut to use on this page.

Anything similar to that might exist?

EDIT: that concrete google translate example is now obsolete as google solved it with auto language detection, but the use case remains the same.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [GreaseMonkey](http://www.greasespot.net/) Firefox extension and create a custom script to add `accesskey` attributes to the links you want to click.

With this you can hold down <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+your access key (on windows) or <kbd>control</kbd>+ your access key on mac to hit the link.

There are many scripts on [userscripts.org](http://userscripts.org) which you can use to help write your script. Perhaps use the source of a [script for adding Google search result navigation](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/5081) as a guide